# Looping over columns in R data frame

Tags: r

I want to loop over specific columns in a data frame and create new columns

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
  a   b  c d
2.8   A  A T    
1.9   T  G T 
1.7   G  G A 
2.3   T  T G
```

I would like an output like this:

```
a    b  c   c_1   d d_1
2.8  A  A   2.8   T  0 
1.9. T  G   0     T  1.9 
1.7  G  G   1.7   A  0
2.3  T  T   2.3   G  0
1.2  C  G   0     C  1.2
```

Basically it creates a new column `c_1` or `d_1` with the value equal to a if the letter in c or d is the same as in b and equal to zero if the letter is different.

I can do that for only one single column:

```
df$c_1 <-ifelse(df$c==df$b,df$a,0)
```

However I have many columns (around 100), how to do that for all the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` (dd is the name of the dataframe):

```
bind_cols(dd,transmute_at(dd, 3:4, ~ifelse(.==dd$b, dd$a,0)))
```

Transmute creates a dataframe with only the new columns. the `3:4` is where I select which columns get changed - in this case simply by giving a vector of their indexes. Finally, `bind_cols` is the `dplyr` variation on cbind, which renames the new columns to avoid duplicates.

Result:

```
    a b c d  c1  d1
1 2.8 A A T 2.8 0.0
2 1.9 T G T 0.0 1.9
3 1.7 G G A 1.7 0.0
4 2.3 T T G 2.3 0.0
```

If you want the columns sorted like in your example you can add this:

```
%>% .[,sort(names(.))]
```

Which will give you:

```
    a b c  c1 d  d1
1 2.8 A A 2.8 T 0.0
2 1.9 T G 0.0 T 1.9
3 1.7 G G 1.7 A 0.0
4 2.3 T T 2.3 G 0.0
```